# sharepoint power bi libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server, libraries, powerbi, python

I published power bi reports to cloud service. Power BI reports include python codes but python path is connected to SharePoint folder. But the problem is the python libraries. How can I install python libraries to the SharePoint to in order to work with python.
Thanks